# Redundancy of type declaration with static variables in a class?

Tags: c++, class, static

So I have this problem for a while now. I just couldn't find the answer to the question. Why do I have to give the data type twice while using static variables inside a class?

Here's an example:

```
#include <iostream>

class Test{
public:
static int test;
};

//right here is the point of confusion
int Test::test = 10;


int main(){
Test test;
std::cout << test.test << "\n";
}
```

As you can see from my program above I had to initialize the variable this way. But what about the duplicate data type specification? Why did I have to write the "int" data type twice? Once already in the class and then again? What is the underlying reason? Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: FYI: [error: non-const static data member must be initialized out of line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61519399/7478597)

Comment: _Why did I have to write the "int" data type twice?_ Because the rules of the language (actually the grammar) requires this. The rules were made by Bjarne Stroustrup (and the standard committee) the heritage of C involved where C++ evolved from.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But new memory is not allocated, right?

Comment: @JasonLiam Got any links to related SO posts? I think it's an interesting question, and I haven't seen it being discussed before.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes, i have some links. I am adding them in the dupe list one by one. The answer is simple because *"the declaration inside the class is not a definition and only a declaration"*. So you must still define the variable somewhere.

Comment: I did.. I didn't find anything though. Shall I just remove my post?

Comment: @JasonLiam I don't see how the dupe is related. OP doesn't ask why a definition is needed, but why the grammar for it requires spelling a type the second time.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat No the declaration and the definition must match for a static variable. Doesn't it? Also, a definition is also a declaration. So the reason `int` is required in the definition is the same as to why it is required in the declaration.

Comment: @JasonLiam Yes, they have to have the same type, but I have no idea why you're required to spell the type in the definition at all, if it could be inferred from the declaration. Other than simplifying the grammar.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat For example, you can write `extern int i;` and then somewhere(in some other source file)  `int i = 0;`. The former is a declaration only. You must include `int` while definning it also. The fundamental reason is the same. It is the same as asking why we need `int` in `extern int i;`.

Comment: @JasonLiam I know how this works. *"You must include int while definning it also"* Yes, and OP asks why, if the type should be known from the declaration. Yes, allowing the type to be omitted would require a different grammar.

Comment: @JasonLiam No I don't think so. Because when we would declare another variable double i in the other cpp file, we would explicitly say that this variable doesn't match the extern call. And so the linker would have to look somewhere else. Because the linker is envolved here, I think the data type should be interpreted in another way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why did I have to write the "int" data type twice?

Because there are 3 components of a `simple-declaration`, namely `attributes`, `specifiers` and `declarators` and a definition(like the one you provided) is also a declaration so it has to follow these rules. Now, the second of these component, `specifier` **indicate the type**, storage class or other properties of the entity that is being declared and **is not optional**.

This means that when providing the definition for the static data member, you still need to provide the `type-specifier` according to the grammar. This also means that you can use `decltype(Test::test)` instead of `int` when defining the static data member outside the class.

The point is that the current grammar requires us to specify the `type` when defining.

Comment: Thank you! That cleared all doubt!

Answer (score 2):

You don't 'have to' duplicate as long as you provide the type somehow. Grammar requires a type there that cannot be auto (which is not type, but usually people expect to be able to write it in place of a type), but you can still let the compiler deduce it:

```
    #include <iostream>
     
    class Test{
    public:
        static int test;
    };
     
    //right here is the point of confusion
    decltype(Test::test) Test::test = 10;
     
     
    int main(){
        Test test;
        std::cout << test.test << "\n";
    }
```

If you don't like duplicating type name, you might write a macro for it.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question is why it is required at all and not how to workaround it. Why can't we omit `decltype(Test::test)` and `int` when defining the static data member.

Comment: @JasonLiam I wrote, 'grammar requires'. You wrote the details of the grammar, but the main cause is that grammar requires user to write it. And there's absolutely no further reason - you could define a grammar where `@def` simbolizes it. But C++ is not that grammar - so I think I answered it.

Comment: I see but note that there is still duplication in your example. We still have to write `Test::test` inside the `decltype`. OP seems to be asking why we can't omit it(the `int` part and the `decltype(Test::test) part` completely. Basically, because the grammar requires it.

Comment: @JasonLiam Please read my answer before trying to find an error in it. I've explained: if you don't like duplicating name, you might write a macro for it. `DEF(Test::Test) = 10;` has no duplication and it's trivial to define.

Comment: It's not that I don't like the duplicated name. My problem with your answer was that you've written in the first line of your answer *"you don't have to"* which is wrong. Because we still need provide a type. Now whether we do it by directly writing `int` or `decltype(Test::test)` is irrelevant. If you were to clarify that quoted statement like by changing it to something like *"You don't have to write `int` explicitly as you can also write `decltype(Test::test)` but anyhow the type must be provided"* then your answer will be more clear.

Comment: @JasonLiam I think it was clear that I refer to duplicating, and not to write there something or not; but just to make sure, I wrote now explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about the rationale, then nobody (except probably Bjarne himself) knows for sure. Such things were rarely publicly discussed or written down when the language was conceived. But if I had to guess, I'd say that it is to make the language rules simple and get the language out of the door faster. Every declaration needs a type. That's essential in the formulation of the grammar. If you change such a fundamental thing willy-nilly, you risk opening a huge can of worms.

Comment: Yeah exactly.. I was wondering about that. Probably I'll never know..