# In-class vs out-of-class static member initialization: const(expr)ness and ODR

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, constexpr, static-members, one-definition-rule

Experimentally, I know how to declare/initialize/define `static` data member of various kinds (mainly by reading the compiler diagnosis) yet I realize that I don't really understand the rules behind these mechanics and the One-Definition-Rule but I have issues with understanding behind the logic of `static` data member initialization and respect of ODR.
My confusion is increased by differences in behavior according to `const`-ness, `constexpr`-ness.
I found several posts on SO speaking about `static` data members and ODR but I'm unsure that they address exactly my questions below. At least, none that I read was able to give me *the big picture*, all in one place.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static provides the rules regarding `static` data members but I don't fully understand it with respect to One-Defintion-Rule.

Let say I have the following files.

ClassODR.h

```cpp
struct CData {
#ifdef IN_CLASS_DEFINITION
    static int m_Value = 3;
#else
    static int m_Value;
#endif

#ifdef IN_CLASS_CONST_DEFINITION
    static int const m_kValue = 3;
#else
    static int const m_kValue;
#endif

#ifdef IN_CLASS_CONSTEXPR_DEFINITION
    static double constexpr m_kfValue = 3.14;
#else
    static double constexpr m_kfValue;
#endif
};

#ifdef OUT_OF_CLASS_IN_HEADER_DEFINITION
int CData::m_Value = 3;
#endif

#ifdef OUT_OF_CLASS_CONST_IN_HEADER_DEFINITION
int const CData::m_kValue = 3;
#endif

#ifdef OUT_OF_CLASS_CONSTEXPR_IN_HEADER_DEFINITION
constexpr double m_kfValue = 3.14;
#endif
```

ClassODR.cpp

```cpp
#ifndef OUT_OF_CLASS_IN_HEADER_DEFINITION
int CData::m_Value = 3;
#endif

#ifndef IN_CLASS_CONST_DEFINITION
#ifndef OUT_OF_CLASS_CONST_IN_HEADER_DEFINITION
int const CData::m_kValue = 3;
#endif
#endif

#ifndef IN_CLASS_CONSTEXPR_DEFINITION
#ifndef OUT_OF_CLASS_CONSTEXPR_IN_HEADER_DEFINITION
int const CData::m_kfValue = 3.14;
#endif
#endif
```

`OUT_OF_whatever_IN_HEADER_DEFINITION` could be only defined if `IN_whatever_DEFINITION` is not.

TestODRUse#N.cpp

```cpp
void TestODRUse#N() {
    std::cout << CData::m_Value << '\n';
    std::cout << CData::m_kValue << '\n';
    std::cout << CData::m_kfValue << '\n';
}
```

main.cpp

```cpp
int main() {
    TestODRUse1();
    TestODRUse2();  // testing for ODR violations
}
```

Other trivial header files and `#include` directives required as glue between the different files are omitted on purpose for clarity sake.
The full example is available [here](https://godbolt.org/z/YGTnjPTr3).

These are some observations (for the record and the sake of exhaustiveness) and some questions.

1- If any `OUT_OF_whatever_IN_HEADER_DEFINITION` is set, there is an ODR violation: corresponding variable is defined in TestODR1 and TestODR2 translation unit. No question there. Besides, the situation can be alleviate by declaring the variable `inline` from C++17 on.

2- I was wondering why the `static` non-`const` member could not be initialized in-line, I found that answer that explain that it is in order to avoid ODR violation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61519186

3- But on the other hand, situation changes as soon as the data is declared `const(expr)`.
`static const(expr)` member can (must) be initialized in-line: thus each translation unit see a definition but there is no ODR violation: why?

5- Eventually the following paragraph, from the cppreference page linked above, regarding `constexpr static` data member, puzzles me:

> If a const non-inline(since C++17) static data member or a constexpr static data member(since C++11)(until C++17) is odr-used, a definition at namespace scope is still required, but it cannot have an initializer.
> namespace scope for constexpr
> The following example is given:

```cpp
struct X
{
    static const int n = 1;
    static constexpr int m = 4;
};
 
const int *p = &X::n, *q = &X::m; // X::n and X::m are odr-used
const int X::n;             // … so a definition is necessary
constexpr int X::m;         // … (except for X::m in C++17)
```

Yet I think that I never had to redefined, out-of-class an in-class initialized `static constexpr` data member.

To sum it up, I'd like clarification on the ODR for `static` data members according to their const(expr)-ness. Thanks to specify what may be the differences regarding the different C++ versions.

Comment: I am absolutely sure I saw this question yesterday and commented on it.   (10k+ to view deleted Q): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77476976/in-class-vs-out-of-class-static-member-initialization-and-odr   In general you should improve your existing question rather than deleting and reposting.

Comment: @BenVoigt Indeed, I merely follow your advice and split the question in two (though I could have cut the original one in two and make a new one, my first impulse was to write 2 questions and delete the original one)